# C++ design decisions: one header for muliple source files... or not

Tags: c++

Similar questions have been asked in StackOverflow but nothing quite answer my problem, so here it goes:

In my program I will have a lot of functions like: `createCamera()`, `createCube()`, `createSphere()`, etc. probably with different signatures as well. As of now I see three different options to organize my files:

1. Create one *creationCommands.hpp* file and add there all declarations
   of my functions. Create *creationCommands.cpp* file and add there all
   definitions of those functions. This solution doesn't suit me becasue
   I will eventually end up with uber source file.
2. Create one *creationCommands.hpp* file, add there all declarations of my functions and create seperate source files (e.g.
   *createCube.cpp*) for definitions. This way I will be able to easily
   view all my declarations in one place and avoid one big source file.
3. Create separate header and source files for all commands and include
   them (header files) in *creationCommands.hpp* for convenience
       sake. This method yields a lot of header files that will only
       consist of only one or two function declarations, which I don't know if it's
       good or not.

The question is: what of those three options will be the best in my case? Or maybe there are different ways to solve this.

Comment: I don't think there's an objective way to answer that. And even if there was, the scope of it seems too broad for SO IMO.

Comment: On second thought, it *may* be on-topic over at [softwareengineering.se]. So try asking there.

Comment: Are you writing OOP code? If yes, then there is great simplicity in having one public class per a pair of .h and .cpp. If the .cpp becomes too big, it may be time to refactor the class so it has less code in it. If you are not writing OOP code, it's harder to divide things up sensibly. In any case there is no single answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat - To be honest I didn't expect this to remain open and undeleted for so long.

Comment: @gnat - Also, as a major contributer to SE, do you think this is a good fit as is? I'd flag for migration if I was sure.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to declare all of the `createXXX()` functions in one header?   Apart from the fact they have `create` in their name, there is no other obvious relationship or connection between them.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you what to choose. Any of this approaches should not cause problems during compilation or run-time stages.

Although if you work among other programmers on some project, then you may have some code convention, which may allow or restrict some of this approaches.

Anyway, it also depends on usage of these files in the project. For example, if *createCube* is used only with *createCamera* and *createSphere*, then creation of 3 header files is obviously stupid idea.

Answer (score 0):

One way that some project use is to create several level of header file:

```
allCommands.hpp
|___cameraCommands.hpp
|___cubeCommands.hpp
|___sphereCommands.hpp
```

then for each header file except the first one, an equivalent source file with the implementation.

the `allCommands.hpp` file just include the other one, for easier inclusion if you need more than one.

Having one header for each group of function is good because you keep different modules separated, making it easier to eventually change them in the future and reusing them just for the part you really need.